# How to upgrade Django Q and Django without clearing the queue?

Tags: django, python-3.x, queue, django-q

When deploying the project after upgrading Django and Django-Q.
I got the following log.

Is there a way to avoid that error but still keep the tasks running in the queue to avoid downtime?

```html
08:59:03 [Q] INFO Process-1:440 pushing tasks at 12192
Process Process-1:440:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File “/usr/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/process.py”, line 258, in _bootstrap
self.run()
File “/usr/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/process.py”, line 93, in run
self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
File “/home/ubuntu/py34env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django_q/cluster.py”, line 340, in pusher
task = SignedPackage.loads(task[1])
File “/home/ubuntu/py34env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django_q/signing.py”, line 31, in loads
serializer=PickleSerializer)
File “/home/ubuntu/py34env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django_q/core_signing.py”, line 36, in loads
return serializer().loads(data)
File “/home/ubuntu/py34env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django_q/signing.py”, line 44, in loads
return pickle.loads(data)
AttributeError: Can’t get attribute ‘simple_class_factory’ on <module ‘django.db.models.base’ from ‘/home/ubuntu/py34env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py’>
```